# workstation getting self-assigned IP after static IP configured

Tags: windows, networking, static-ip

SO I have a client whos DC went down. With it offline I went ahead and assigned static IP's to all workstations (win 8.1) so they would still have internet and recreated a file-share off of a single workstation. They are up and running with one problem. 2 of the workstations will not take a static IP. I'll configure them, bounce the system and ipconfig only to see a self-assigned ip. I've reset TCP/IP on the box as per this [doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/299357?p=1) from MS. I've updated the drivers for the NIC. I'm stumped. This is working just fine for other workstation on the network. Although as a side note, all system have the networks classified as a public network.

Comment: Did you by accident configure both machines to the same IP? That was the reason I had this problem last time, duplicate IPs.

Comment: I want to say no because but I'm going to check again just to make sure.

Comment: You know sometime when you are so confident in something you end up looking foolish. It was a dup from the phone system, thanks for the clear thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the IP address you assign isn't already in use.

Windows uses a self assigned IP address even though a static address is assigned when duplicate IP addresses are in use on the network.

You can check this by running `ipconfig` on the command line, the `IPv4 address` line will have `(duplicate)` after the static IP address if this is the case.